# Rails User setup wizard

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After a user creates a profile in my RoR application (with Devise) and they sign into my application I'd like to 'lead' them through the next steps they should do, such as complete their user profile, add a location, setup notifications, etc.

I was looking at Ryan Bates' Wicked railscast, but it looks like it's related to a specific controller, whereas the various things I mentioned above could be in multiple controllers.

What suggestions/options exist for me?